# How to change the icon for Network Monitor Applet?

Tags: applet

I want to change my network monitor applet to this [image] icon.Currently my network monitor applet has this icon [image].I am using ubuntu 10.04,how to do this?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do what you wish without root privileges or even overwriting anything.  As you know, your icon themes are located in **/usr/share/icons**.  Simply go to your icon theme directory and locate the icon(s) you wish to replace, taking note of their locations.

In your home folder there is a hidden directory called **.icons**.  In Nautilus you can hit **Ctrl+H** to see it.  Any icons you put in this directory will be treated as icons are treated in **/usr/share/icons**.  The only catch is that icons places in the .icons folder available only for that user.  Also programs run as superuser, like Synaptic, will not reflect any changes in theme-ing added to your home folder.

A way to solve that is to symbolically link ~/.icons (and ~/.themes if you want) to the corresponding folders in /root.

If you wanted to do that you could put this in terminal:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.icons /root
```

That will make your user themes globally available without needing root privileges at all.  But that's beyond the scope of the question and I'm babbling.

I will use the Mint-X icon theme and the application Blender as an example.

- When I navigate to
  **/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/48** I see a Blender icon.  But I would like
  to replace it with a custom icon.
- I then go to **~/.icons** and recreate
  the same directory hierarchy, staring with "**Mint-X**":
- ~/.icons/Mint-X/apps/48
- Then I put my custom Blender icon in
  the new "**48**" folder.
- And finally, I open the Appearance Preferences
  Window, select a different icon
  theme, and reselect Mint-X so it
  reloads (sometimes it happens live
  and you don't even need to reload the
  theme).

Now instead of the Blender icon in **/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/48** I see the one in **~/.icons/Mint-X/apps/48** used in apps and menus that use the 48x48 sized Blender icon.

**Keep in mind that everything is case sensitive and must match each other exactly for this trick to work!**

There a few other ways to do this without overwriting anything in an icon theme, but this is by far the simplest.  Also, **just putting your custom icon in ~/.icons often works** (the Twitter client Hotot is an example).

I recommend learning what the **index.theme** files do.  Those files control what places your system looks to decide which icons to use, what to name the theme, etc.  Open one up in Gedit and have a look, it's pretty simple!

The way I do it is by keeping a custom theme in ~/.icons that I always use (to make sure panel icons are the correct colors, mostly).  I make up an index.theme file (you can copy one rather than write a whole new one, but make sure your folder locations correlate!) and just have it "inherit" the new theme I want.

So if I wanted to use the Elementary icon theme instead of the Faenza-Dark one I would change the line

```
Inherits=Faenza-Dark
```

to

```
Inherits=Elementary
```

So in turn, by inheriting Elementary I will also inherit whatever Elementary inherits, but **my icons will always come first**.

Hope that was helpful, time for bed!

Comment: Can you try to format your answer with bold, emphasis, code and maybe bulleted lists and headings. Because for now it is very hard to read.

Comment: I am using Faenza-Dark theme icon sets..And this is my network monitor applets in Faenza-Dark theme(http://imgur.com/NuWNj.png) i want to replace these icons with this one(http://imgur.com/TdDwl.png) But i am confused i have many icons in Faenza-Dark icon sets.What should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35662

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: I am not using the Human icon pack.Am using the tropical icon pack.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I meant to give you this link just so that you could check the concept, I think you should just find your theme folder there & search for the icon responsible for the network applet.

Comment: I have found but the problems is all those icons are in .svg format.The icon that i am going to replace is in .png format.What should i do now?

Comment: @karthick87: GIMP, imagemagick.

Comment: Can some explain me step by step?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/convert/image/svg2raster.htm

This might be an easy solution. Give it a shot, I didn't try it.

Comment: Replacing the icon is the same, whether you use .svg or .png. You can overwrite the .svg with a .png icon file. svg files are better at scaling than png.

Comment: Where should i replace it?Coz inside my icon folder i can see a lot of folders(actions,appa,categories,devices,emblems,mimetypes,places & status)

Comment: @charlie-tca : No, we can't overwrite a .svg with a .png. We can _remove_ the svg and use a png instead.

Answer (score 1):

The icon name in use there is the '*network-transmit-receive*' .

So what you need to do is, Name your favorite icon as 'network-transmit-receive.png'/'network-transmit-receive.svg' depending on what format you have in your theme. 
Either replace it or just add one if your theme does not have the 'network-transmit-receive' icon.

Other icon names used, *at times*, in the applet are the "network-idle", "network-receive", "network-transmit" .